# How to test whether a variable is changing over time?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, trend, augmented-dickey-fuller, test-for-trend

I have a variable called `pct_spread(i,t)` which is calculated as `(ask_price(i,t) - bid_price(i,t))/ask_price(i,t)` based on ask and bid prices from a broker for different stocks `i` and time `t`. This variable is calculated on a minute by minute basis and spans around 20 years.

I would like to know how can I test whether this variable is changing over time? What data frequency would you recommend? Should I be using the Dickey-Fuller test for stationarity?

UPDATE:

Based on the comments I have received I am reformulating the question here.

I want to estimate the average per-year change in the spread cost and test it against the null of no change.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Of course this variable changed over time.  The first thing to determine, then, is what constitutes a change that might be interesting or meaningful.  After you supply that, it might be possible to provide some useful advice.

Comment: I know the formulation of the problem is a bit broad, but this is the general hypothesis I want to test, whether the spread changes of time. It is up to me to determine the rest, such as frequency or which test to use. The data is basically in panel form. Obviously I would have stock fixed effects, but I am not sure how to go about this problem.

Comment: Just a clarification: Did you mean "this variable changed over time" or "the **coefficient** of this variable changed over time"?

Comment: I mean the variable. but would be interested to also know what's the difference when testing for variation in the variable and in the coefficient of the variable

Comment: I am trying to suggest you don't need a test: you have such an enormous amount of data that *any* test will conclude the variable is changing.  Consider finding out *how* it has been changing.